# Pointer-to-pointers addresses & arithmetic

Tags: c, pointer-to-pointer

programmers!

I am totally sunk with double pointer (pointer-to-pointers)...  Many questions here!

Let's start with this task:  I am writing my custom version of 'calloc' func, which must return pointer to 'n' memory elements of size 'size'. Here is what I invented:

```
void **calloc1(int n, int size)
{
    int i, j;
    char *tmp, **p = NULL;
    tmp = (char *) malloc1(n * size);
    p = tmp;
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        p[i] = tmp;
        for (j = 0; j < size; j++)
            tmp++;
    }
    p = &p[0];
    return (void **)p;
}
/* I entered n==4, size==3;  real pointers are: p[0] == 0x804cfe0; p[1] == 0x804cfe3; p[2] == 0x804cfe6; ... */
```

So, essentially I allocate n*size bytes, and then "assign" array of pointers of equal 'size' to corresponding start positions.
Let's enter n=4 and size=3; it means p[0] points to tmp[0], p[1] to tmp[3], p[2] to tmp[6] and so on.
In GDB, I track pointers values almost after each step.

Then, in 'main' I declare a double pointer and "attach" it to buffer received from my 'calloc':

```
int main (short argc, char **argv)
    {
        char **space;
        space = (char **) calloc1(n, size);   /* removing '(char**)' here does not have effect */ 

    /*  at this stage pointers seems to be correctly "located": 'space' == 'space[0]' == 0x804cfe0; 'space[1]' == 0x804cfe3; 'space[2]' == 0x804cfe6; ... */
```

1) Here is already the first question:  how can 'main()' (or any other function which I will pass a copy of **p) will know the size of pointer arithmetic?  For example, how 'main()' knows that if I add '1' to 'space' (or simply increment it once), it should point to its second pointer (in 'calloc' it's p[1]), which (in this particular case) is 3 chars further of first pointer (p[0])?
Moreover, if I create in 'alloc' array of pointers to strings with "variable length" (for example, p[0] points to tmp[0], p[1] to tmp[7], p[2] to tmp[11] etc.), how will any other function know where it should increment "upper" pointer by 4 and where by 7 "chars"?

Alright, we move further, I try to put some chars into acquired buffer:

```
int i = 0, j = 0, n, size;
char nn, ssize, c, temp[3];

printf ("Enter number/size \n");
sc = scanf ("%c/%c", &nn, &ssize);
n = nn - '0';  /* n==4 */
size = ssize - '0';   /* size==3 */ 

printf ("Enter a 'number' of words\n");
while (j < n) {
    for (i = 0; (c = getchar()) != EOF && i < size; i++)
        *(*space)++ = c; 
    (*space)--;   /* this line is unneccesary; if I remove it - nothing changes */
    ++j;
    ++space;
}
```

2) And here is the evidence for first question: actually, when I increment 'space' here, it moves not by 3 but by 4 chars (after first '++' it is 0x804cfe4, after second 0x804cfe8). Why?  Is there some connection to 'float'-type size?
After first such an incrementing, '*space' points to 0x804cfe6... I do not think it is correct.

I have tried another way - refering to 'space' like not pointer but array:

```
....
while (j < n) {
    for (i = 0; (c = getchar()) != EOF && i < size; i++)
        *space[j]++ = c; 
    space[j]--;
    ++j;
}
```

3) In this case, pointers seems to be ok - e.g. space[1] == 0x804cfe3, space[2] == 0x804cfe6.  The problem is, while this loop is operating with j == 2, value of 'space[0]' somehow changes from 0x804cfe2 (moved twice - ok) to something like 0x6a04cfe2 (which is out of bounds). What the h.. ???

4) And at all, there is some weird behavior of addresses. I have also tried not to write chars directly to **space, but to use string copy function:

```
    char i, temp[3];  
    ...
    while (j < n) {
        for (i = 0; (c = getchar()) != EOF && i < size; i++)
            temp[i] = c; 
        strncpy1 (space[j],temp,3);
        ++j;
    }
.....
void strncpy1 (char *s, char *t, int k)
{
    while (--k > 0) {
        *s = *t;
        s++;  t++;
    }
}
```

Inside copy func, copying and incrementing show in GDB correct. But after returning from 'strncpy1', space[j] changes from 0x804cfe0 to something like 0x804000a.  How is it possible that called function is able to affect parents' (external) pointer?

So finally, what type is pointer-to-char-pointers? What size does it have?

Comment: I don't understand what you are trying to do with your calloc function. Why does it return `void **` instead of returning `void *` like the regular calloc does?

Comment: Yes, I expected for such a question ))  anyway, changing calloc1 from 'void **' to 'void *' (and returning pointer type from '(void **)p' to '(void *)p' as well) does not have any effect...

Comment: Before doing anything else, draw a memory map on paper of where your memory allocations are, and where each pointer is pointing to.

Comment: In 3) you're writing 'j' into it, right? Which is 0x6A, which when set to the third place in your overlapping memory will change the pointer's fourth byte. See my answer for details.

Comment: I don't think you understand what `calloc` does.  It **does not** allocate an array of pointers.  All it does is malloc n*size bytes and clear those bytes to zero.  There are no pointers to pointers anywhere in calloc.  If you are trying to write something different, please explain what you are trying to do because your program makes no sense at the moment.

Comment: I'm completing K&R book tasks, specifically - writing custom version of 'calloc(n,s)'.  I have not yet looked into built-in version (and I do not want to - I must make it myself !).  And the best idea that came to my mind was allocating 'n*s' bytes with 'malloc', and then assign a pointer-to-n-pointers (of size 's') to these bytes.   Anyway thank you all, guys, I feel my brain will soon rejoice at this )

Comment: `void *calloc(int n, int size) { void *ret = malloc(n*size); memset(ret, 0, n*size); return ret; }`  This is all that `calloc()` is.  I didn't mean that you needed to look at the source code for it.  I meant that you didn't understand that the function returned one single pointer.

Answer (score 1):

I believe on your system size of pointer is 4, and since you are using a pointer to pointer and then incrmeneting it so it adds 4 byte into current location to reach next pointer of its type(char**).

NOTE: you are not incrementing pointer to char, you are incrementing pointer to pointer.

Now again if i talk about your second question that how function will know where to increase 4 and where 7 so it not related to function. Because array of pointer does of pointer address which are saved on consecutive location(they are not value of pointer, i am talking about pointers which are save in array of pointer) so it will just increment that pointer by one and will reach to next pointer of its type weather it is on P[0] or P[4] or p[7]..

Comment: Hi, Dayal!   Yes thanx, I see I increment pointer to not char but another pointer.  I think I begin to understand...   So "main" ("upper") pointer here is actually a consecutive memory location, right?  And what is this location length? What is the size of one pointer position -1/2/4 bytes?

Comment: since this a pointer array so each location will have 4 byte.

Answer (score 1):

The biggest problem you have is that you are using the same memory location for pointers and data. That is why you are seeing this strange behaviour.

You allocate only one buffer, then use this buffer to contain the pointers into the same buffer. Of course when you then modify the contents, your pointers will change. You must have separate memory locations: one for the data, another for the pointers to that data.

If you really want to do this, you could do it this way:

```
void **calloc1(int n, int size)
{
    int i, j;
    char *tmp, **p = NULL;
    tmp = (char *) malloc1(n * size);
    p = (char**) malloc1(n * sizeof(char*));
...
```

**NOTE**: this way you will naturally need *two* calls to free the memory, and you might not have any way of knowing what the second one is, since the user can change the pointers. So even better would be to combine the allocations into one:

```
void **calloc1(int n, int size)
{
    int i, j;
    char *tmp, **p = NULL;
    p = (char**) malloc1(n * size + n * sizeof(char*));
    tmp = (char *) (p + n);
...
```

This way there is one allocation pointed to by p, but pointers will have separate memory from the actual items.

As to the other questions:

> 1) how can 'main()' know the size of pointer arithmetic?

Pointers always have fixed size. They're pointers, they don't care about what they point to. sizeof(char*) == sizeof(int*) == sizeof(yourcoolstruct*)

> 2) when I increment 'space' here, it moves not by 3 but by 4 chars (after first '++' it is 0x804cfe4, after second 0x804cfe8). Why? Is there some connection to 'float'-type size?

Because in your system sizeof(pointer) == 4, so every pointer takes 4 bytes. Normal in 32bit environments and has nothing to do with floats, ints or anything.

> 3) while this loop is operating with j == 2, value of 'space[0]' somehow changes from 0x804cfe2 (moved twice - ok) to something like 0x6a04cfe2 (which is out of bounds). What the h.. ???

Because you use the same memory for pointers and data. You write 'j' (0x6A in hex) into space[1][0], which points to the fourth byte of the allocation. Which also is the most significant byte of the space[0] pointer, so it becomes that.

Comment: Thanks, Sami!   Actually, I am just finishing my exploration of Kernigan-Ritchie, and got stuck with final tasks, dealing with memory.   
So here, hmm...  Do not strings like  'char *tmp, **p = NULL;'  or 'char **space;'  make necessary allocation for these pointers?  I am asking because, through all examples in the book and in all its tasks (which I have successfully completed) there were no any special memory allocation for variables, pointers, etc.  They (us) just declare some pointer and then assign some value to it (e.g. char *ptr, b[5];    ptr = b;)

Comment: Yes, `char **p` will allocate memory *for the pointer to the pointers*, but of course the memory that contains the *pointers* has to be allocated separately. And if those *pointers* point to some *data*, that also must be allocated in some way. If you use `char b[5]` then you are explicitly allocating five chars worth of memory compile-time and can naturally use it without any allocations.